# How to select successive words backwards with `C-M-SPC` (`mark-sexp`)?

Tags: emacs, selection, s-expression

I tried to select three successive words using `C-M-SPC SPC SPC`.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Repeating `SPC` selects additional words in a forward direction.

How can I do the same thing in a backward direction, e.g. starting after `lazy` and selecting backward through `over`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a negative prefix arg, e.g. `M--` or `C--`:

```
C-- C-M-SPC SPC SPC SPC
```

As is often the case, when a positive numeric prefix arg means do something forward a negative prefix arg means do it backward.